# Locally Free Replacement Sheaf on 3-Fold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $\scr{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on a smooth $3$-dimensional algebraic variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$. Suppose that $\scr{F}$ fails to be locally free at only finitely many points of $X$, called "bad" points. Under what conditions on $\scr{F}$ does there exist a unique locally free sheaf $\scr{F}'$ that agrees with $\scr{F}$ away from the "bad" points?

(In the $2$-dimensional case, the answer is the double-dual sheaf $\scr{F}^{\vee\vee}$.)

Comment: You meant double dual and not the dual. That is in general all you can do. If the double dual is a vector bundle, you are done, otherwise there is no such vector bundle.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for the correction; to clarify, are you saying that if the double dual is not locally free, then it is possible to prove that there is no such vector bundle?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.